# In vs code and code . in command prompt not working in windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

'code .' is not working in commad prompt.i have added environmental path like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin" but not working also i refered some stackoverflow link but not worning properly.I do not know how to set So i need clarity how to set this option?

Comment: From docs: _You might need to log off after the installation for the change to the %PATH% environmental variable to take effect._

Comment: I tried. but not working .Getting this message.C:\xampp\htdocs\Angular>code
'code' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Apple Orange, what return `where code` command? Use you the 32 bit version of VS Code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Execute `where code` command in `cmd` to find correct path.

Example of the result:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd
```

or

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd
```

> 2. Add `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin` or `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin` to windows `PATH` variable.
> 3. Restart your console for the change to the `PATH` variable to take effect.
> 4. Verify that the VS Code path has been added to the `PATH` variable using `reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` command in `cmd`.